# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug'

Tags: android, gradle

When I ran my project, this error pops up, I clean, catch and restart and rebuild the project, but the error remains. 
here is my gradle.build :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sanam.sockettesthttp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
      optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}

}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I solved my problem by deleting `.gradle`  file on my project root and rebuilt my project again.